# How to set next day or after two day alarm

Tags: android

supposed today is Wednesday now i want to set alarm (8am) Thursday or Friday . i already tried many way but alarm is not triggering  , here is  code github-:https://github.com/JaberAhamed/alarmClock

```
 Calendar calSet = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar  now=Calendar.getInstance();
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,week);
    calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minuts);
    calSet.set(Calendar.AM_PM, formate);
    calSet.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

    if (calSet.before(now)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "before ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        calSet.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,1);
    }

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    int pos = position+ week;
    intent.putExtra("extra", "yes");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, pos, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calSet.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: You can share the device you are testing. And if you want the set Thursday or Friday you can use:
 
    calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calender.THURSDAY).

then you check if the alarm has expired, you can call:
    calSet.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,7);

Comment: I am testing in android emulators Nexus 5x API

Comment: no, I have a little confusion here, you can call: calSet.add (Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 7);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I research, You can use alarmManager with Calendar, It will solve your problem.

At first, you need to detect current day of week and you counting it more 1 or 2 day and set into your alarm

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentDayOfWeek = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)
calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, currentDayOfWeek + 2);
calSet.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 8);
calSet.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
```

Hope it can help you!

Fix me if I have any wrong !

Comment: is not working because if i want to set Mon day alarm  but currentDayOfWeek is Sat day not (7+2=9) how solve it

Comment: Yeah, you can mod for 7,

In your case, current is `Sat = 7`
now `Sat + 2 = 9`. Ok, `9%7 = 2` and it will be `Monday`.

So just change a little in this line:
`calSet.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, (currentDayOfWeek + 2)%7);
`
Tell me it work or not! Thanks

Comment: its not work, can you please see the full code my github link https://github.com/JaberAhamed/alarmClock

Comment: Tell me what error or warning from your IDE?
I'm just give you an idea, may be syntax you need to check by yourself !?